# Is there a good single byte delimeter for use with utf-8 strings that isn't a null terminator?

Tags: parsing, strings, utf-8

I'm looking for a quick way to split strings containing individual JSON payloads. Currently, I'm using newlines and searching for the newline ASCII character, but I figure if I start using utf-8 this could easily break.

Is there any quick single byte character that I would be able to use besides a null terminator that I can use to split strings by that won't be thrown off by utf-8 or appear in the JSON payload?

Comment: "if I start using utf-8 this could easily break" – How? I don't see how that could happen.

Comment: So the newline ASCII character will never accidentally appear in UTF-8, you're saying?

Comment: Yes. Characters in the ASCII range will be encoded exactly the same as in ASCII, characters outside of the ASCII range are encoded as a multi-octet sequence of 2-6 octets, all of which have their high-order bit (i.e. the 8th bit) set; since ASCII only uses 7 bit and the 8th is always 0, there is no possible confusion.

Comment: Might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847982/utf-8-string-delimiter) on another StackExchange.  If you choose to use newline, you might want to add code to treat CR+LF, CR, and LF all the same way; this will address a number of issues that could come up if you work with Unix or Macintosh systems.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What you wrote actually answers my question in the way that I misunderstood things wonderfully! It would make for a fantastic answer.

Comment: Note that, according to Wikipedia, the bytes 0xC0 and 0xC1, as well as the bytes 0xF5 and higher, are never allowed in UTF-8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UTF-8 was specifically designed to be forwards- and backwards-compatible with ASCII, specifically it has these two properties:

- the encoding of characters within the ASCII character set is the same in UTF-8 as it is in ASCII
- all other codepoints are encoded as a sequence of 2-6 octets, all of which have their high-order bit (8th bit) set; since ASCII only uses 7 bits and always has the 8th bit unset, a single-octet ASCII character can never be mistaken for a part of a multi-octet sequence and vice versa

So, assuming that newlines work reliably for you using ASCII, they will also work reliably using UTF-8.

You will have to deal with different newline conventions of different operating systems, either by accepting all of `\r\n` (DOS, Windows), `\r` (Classic MacOS), and `\n` (Unix), or by specifying one and only one (the Internet Standards all use `\r\n`, because they are treated as a newline by all OSs, with maybe some additional garbage attached). And this is not even taking into account the various non-ASCII newline characters defined in Unicode.

However, there is a problem: newlines are valid characters in JSON; they can appear in between any two tokens and are ignored as whitespace

AFAICS, it is not that easy to find a character that is guaranteed to not appear in JSON. The spec is a bit vague, it talks about "whitespace" being allowed, but it does not specify what "whitespace" actually means.

One way to get around this, is to enclose the JSON documents into a JSON list, essentially making the JSON objects just elements of an outer JSON array.

Another way would be to switch to a different language: as of version 1.2, YAML is a proper superset of JSON, meaning that every valid JSON document is also a valid YAML document. One of the features YAML has that JSON doesn't, is a document end marker that allows you to put multiple documents into the same bytestream. So, if you just insert a YAML document end marker in between your JSON documents, you have a valid stream consisting of multiple YAML documents.

Comment: Enclosing the JSON documents into a JSON list is the most sane option.  I was going to answer that, but you covered it.

Comment: I might prefer a JSON dictionary, because then I don't need to worry about the order of items, I can leave out things that are not needed, and I can add things with backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't appear in *your* payload, any single-byte ASCII character is a valid separator, because the (ASCII) code points 0 - 127 will be unique, no escaped single bytes will match their values.

See [Wikipedia on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

Single Byte (ASCII) code points will always be encoded as `0xxxxxxx` bits, whereas all bytes of sequences will be encoded as `1xxxxxxx` bits.

So, your line break byte (`0x0A` / dec `10` / bin `00001010`) can only appear if you actually but a line feed there.